# Should detailed data manipulation be performed in C# or SQL Stored Procedures?

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I am rewriting a business application that manages, schedules and builds very large print jobs.

The conditional printing data is very detailed.

The current system was written in Visual FoxPro 9 with SQL Server 2005. All of the data manipulation was written in VFP 9.0.

An example of a print job will have 200,000 names with conditions for each customer based on client. They are over 100 columns that will contain variable data. Each record is a separate printed insert. There could be up to 20 inserts per customer.

There could be up to 200 clients chosen for each print job.

After working with C# for many years, I have not been impressed with the handling of large collections of data with detailed manipulation.

In the past I would have passed a user defined table with parameters for a file and then write all data manipulation code in SQL and store my results in a table with a job id. then have my c# application build the files to export accordingly by job id.

****If you had to build a work file with over 2,000,000 records and over 100 columns per record and write weeks of code to build these records, would you write the code in c# using collections/entity framework or write the code in SQL stored procedures?

I see that people frown upon cursors in SQL, but I have worked on over 20 systems that exclusively manipulate data in SQL stored procedures using record by record cursor loops.

Thank you for your advice

Comment: How many people are going to use your system ? if we're talking 2, 3 people i'd go for SQL, but if the number of people is higher, it would be wiser to go for more C# than SQL (balancing long running jobs client side)

Comment: There will be 1 to 2 people running this particular function at one time. The rest of the system is pretty standard data entry, importing from client files, reporting. That code is using c# and entity framework.

Comment: I'd go server side, a lot of data, a few people, good luck !